# TinyMCE: link auto-completer

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tinymce, wysiwyg

We're using TinyMCE for inside our homebrew CMS. We'd like to simplify linking to other pages on our sites. Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

- As the user is editing inside TinyMCE, they press @, and begin typing something (ex. "Ja"). TinyMCE shows them a list of topics from our site that start with "Ja" (ex. Java, Javascript) in an autocomplete fashion. This is very similar to how Facebook does name autocompletion when you post something to your wall.
- I'd imagine exposing the list of elements to autocomplete in some sort of an endpoint that I'd hit using Ajax.

Is there an existing TinyMCE plugin to do this? Or, do you know of another WYSIWYG editor that has a plugin like that? I really don't want to reinvent the wheel and write a custom plugin - but I of course will do it if necessary.

Thanks in advance! I'd very much appreciate any tips.

-Alex

Comment: Found one possibility: https://github.com/abrimo/TinyMCE-Autocomplete-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily achieved using the UI component "Autocompleter".

Here's the link to the current documentation for TinyMCEv6: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/autocompleter/

Here it is for v5:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/autocompleter/